# How do I use Nokogiri::XML::Reader to parse large XML files?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Ruby's Nokogiri to parse large (1 GB or more) XML files.  I'm testing code on a smaller file, containing only 4 records [available here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1304874/crc.004.xml). I'm using Nokogiri version 1.5.0, Ruby 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 10.10.  Since I don't understand SAX very well, I'm trying Nokogiri::XML::Reader to start.

My first attempt, to retrieve the content of the PMID tag, looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"

file   = ARGV[0]
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(File.open(file))
p      = []
reader.each do |node|
  if node.name == "PMID"
    p << node.inner_xml
  end
end

puts p.inspect
```

Here's what I hoped to see:

```
["21714156", "21693734", "21692271", "21692260"]
```

Here's what I actually saw:

```
["21714156", "", "21693734", "", "21692271", "", "21692260", ""]
```

It seems that for some reason, my code is finding, or generating, an extra, empty PMID tag for every instance of PMID.  Either that or `inner_xml` does not work as I thought.

I'd be grateful if anyone could confirm that my code and data generates the result shown and suggest where I'm going wrong.

Comment: In the "old days", before we had hosts with many GB of RAM, we used to worry about loading in one or two GB of content. Now days, unless there are risks of receiving an unexpected file that would consume all available RAM, I'd try letting Nokogiri and Ruby pull in the full sized file. Yeah, 1GB is a lot of text, but on an 8GB or 16GB system it's nothing. Watch to see if load and processing time improve or are impacted as memory allocation and garbage collection can affect speed; Using the SAX model can help in that case, but I much prefer loading it and treating it like a DOM.

Comment: Speed is more the issue than RAM. For example, I tried parsing with Hpricot (my preferred library) on a shared server with 96 GB RAM: 72 minutes.

Comment: I haven't been following Hpricot for a couple years; I used it a lot but ran into some issues where it exploded consistently in a glorious fashion, and Nokogiri didn't, so I switched and haven't looked back. 72 minutes seems like a long time to run. You might try running the profiler and see if it reveals anything. Otherwise, summarize the code and XML and post it here and we'll try to help speed things up.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each element in the stream comes through as two events: one to open the element and one to close it. The opening event will have

```
node.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT
```

and the closing event will have

```
node.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_END_ELEMENT
```

The empty strings you're seeing are just the element closing events. Remember that with SAX parsing, you're basically walking through a tree so you need the second event to tell you when you're going back up and closing an element.

You probably want something more like this:

```
reader.each do |node|
  if node.name == "PMID" && node.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT
    p << node.inner_xml
  end
end
```

Or perhaps:

```
reader.each do |node|
  next if node.name      != 'PMID'
  next if node.node_type != Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT
  p << node.inner_xml
end
```

Or some other variation on that.