# How to extract attributes and data with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a big file I can't open:

```
... more here

<my_element attr1='123'>
... a lot of text and elements here
</my_element>

<my_element attr1='33'>
... a lot of text and elements here
</my_element>

... more here
```

I tried "[How do I use Nokogiri::XML::Reader to parse large XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675128/how-do-i-use-nokogirixmlreader-to-parse-large-xml-files)":

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"
require "debugger"
require "awesome_print"

file   = ARGV[0]
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(File.open(file))
reader.each do |node|
  if node.name == "PATDOC"
    debugger
    break
  end
end
```

but `node.attributes` returns `{}`.

How could I extract the attributes and inner text from the elements?

Comment: Use an XML parser instead.  It will make your life easier.

Comment: I have a long long file I can't even open, which parser could I use? I am in OS X

Comment: Define "big" and "long".

Comment: about 60 MB compressed.

Comment: Big XML data files should be processed using a streaming "SAX" parser. Nokogiri supports SAX and it's documented. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10588194/128421 also. When the question was asked 60MB was kind-of big, now we could do that on most boxes using Nokogiri's normal DOM parsing in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we use Nokogiri to read the entire file and process it as a DOM. I wrapped the sample XML in another node, to make it valid XML, and used a CSS accessor just 'cause they're easier to read:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
  <my_element attr1='123'> a lot of text and elements here </my_element>
  <my_element attr1='33'>  a lot of text and elements here </my_element>
</xml>
EOT

doc.search('my_element').map{ |n|
  [ n['attr1'], n.children.text ]
}
```

Which looks like:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] "123",
        [1] " a lot of text and elements here "
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "33",
        [1] "  a lot of text and elements here "
    ]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you can do it with `awk`, but the recommended way is an XML parser. Anyway:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="</*my_element[^>]+>"} {print $2, $3}' INPUTFILE
```

Note: it's not the perfect solution, because it really depends on your whole input file. What it does is setting your field separator to the tag, and prints the second and third "column" from the file. You might need to modify it.

Comment: I don't understand this one, it seems to extract all `my_element` elements