# Parsing of big file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, bigdata

I need to parse extremely big XML file (near 50GB), how I can do it with Ruby? It's not possible to split it on chunks, I'v already tried.

Comment: https://github.com/ohler55/ox

Comment: Did you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675128/how-do-i-use-nokogirixmlreader-to-parse-large-xml-files I usually use Nokogiri and stream the XML.

Answer (score 2):

I parsed a 40GB file using `Nokogiri::XML::Reader`.

Structure of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
   <row Id="4">
   <row Id="5">
</posts>
```

Code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

fname = "Posts.xml"
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(File.open(fname))
xml.each do |posts|
  posts.each do |post|
    next if post.node_type == 14 # TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_WHITESPACE
    # do something with post
  end
end
```

I think the answer depends on how you plan to use the data.  In my case, I simply needed to stream the post nodes.